# ASP.NET Core API: How to use MySQL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

Here is my connection string:

```
Server=sql145.main-hosting.eu:3306;Database=u230450666_aspt;User=u230450666_aspt;Password=111111;
```

That I use like this:

```
services.AddDbContext<UsersContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseUrl")));
```

And I can't connect to my database, I got this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The parameter is incorrect
>
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)

Thus I tried with HeidiSQL, as follows:

[image]

and it worked.

So I must miss some settings with `UseSqlServer`..

*(I'm following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro))*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException` is for **Microsoft SQL Server** - but it will **NOT** work for MySQL - those are two **completely different** database systems!

You need to use the appropriate, MySQL-specific classes!

Check out this page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core.html

There is a MySQL connector for Entity Framework Core, and you can use this by specifying:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
   .....         
   optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("Server=sql145.main-hosting.eu:3306;Database=u230450666_aspt;User=u230450666_aspt;Password=111111;");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @marc_s pointed out, you can override `OnConfiguring` to use MySQL.
Or if you wish a cleaner & more "pattern-friendly" way: [check this out](https://github.com/jasonsturges/mysql-dotnet-core)